# Can we add custom shortcuts in code, like how we can press ctr+b on a class and it sends us to class definition?

Tags: java, android-studio

Ok, I'm working in android studio, hopefully works the same in java.
Ideally I would love something like this:

```
//parent addapter is here
friendlyRobotAdapter.setListener(new FriendlyRobotAdapter.DoubleListener() {...}
```

And if I could press ctr+b on the "here" and then opens the parent file when the listener is set(at another comment created by me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a javadoc description inside your code and with the @see tag or {@link } tag add your class, then you can ctr+b on the name to get to the class. This works in android studio, you can either try to copy everything manually, or right click method or class and "copy reference" (but this method looks a bit shabby because although sometimes it just pastes the method without the file, ie #getLayout() or ViewHolder, even in other files)

```
int getItemViewTypeSwitch(int position) {
    if (isActive()){
        /**
         * works on classes
         * @see android.support.v7.widget.CardView
         * {@link android.support.v7.widget.CardView}
         * 
         * on methods
         * {@link me2.iwanttoeat.FR_RecycleViewSettings#getLayout()}
         * @see me2.iwanttoeat.FR_RecycleViewSettings#getLayout()
         * 
         * on subclasses
         * @see FR_Adapter.ViewHolder
         * {@link FR_Adapter.ViewHolder}
         */
        return position;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature in Android Studio out of the box, but it's possible to build a plugin to support this kind of navigation. The main difficulty would be keeping track of where exactly to navigate to, given that line numbers in source code change all the time.

Comment: I know! **cry**  that's why i actually said "at another comment created by me". Currently I'm just writing "//goto file friendlyRobot ctr+f xxx1" where i have another comment "//parrent set listener xxx1" and i just use the find option for xxx1

Answer (score 0):

Ok, not quite what op(me) wanted, but its the fastest so far.Rather than my old method (adding a comment with the file name and a unique word, then using ctr+f in the target file searching for the 2nd comment with the unique word). We also have Bookmarks:

1. Navigate/Bookmarks/Show Bookmarks(shift+F11)
2. Add Bookmark(F11)
3. Add Bookmark with mnemonic(ctr+f11)
4. Numeric mnemonics can be opened by ctr+number (ie ctr+3)
5. Edit Bookmark name (right click on bookmark, edit description)

At least for 10 numeric mnemonics we can do this:

```
//press ctr+3 for parent addapter 
friendlyRobotAdapter.setListener(new FriendlyRobotAdapter.DoubleListener() {...}
```